# Compute complex math (integration, derivation,...)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails-3, math, programming-languages

How can I compute complex math in a programming language like:

1. integration
2. derivation
3. some other non-trivial math

For example for these languages:

- Java
- Ruby on Rails

I know that for C# exists Math.NET, but for the others?

Comment: why do not you ask google?

Comment: @Alexandr maybe because google doesn't provide a human feedback?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about Ruby, but for math in my Java applications I've used [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/). It provides a number of reusable components for probability, statistics, linear algebra, and numerical calculus.

Comment: +1 this lib seems to be a good choice, maybe no more options in terms of Taylor series, limits, Laplace

Answer (score 3):

In java , you can try **[javaCalc](https://code.google.com/p/javacalculus/)**

**the library support**:

1. Parsing standard algebraic expressions (syntax tree) from a string.
2. Simplifying algebraic expressions (factoring, common denominator, trigonometric identities, etc).
3. Applying symbolic standard calculus functions (differentiation, integration) to
   algebraic expressions.
4. Common calculus tools (Taylor series, limits, numerical approximations).
5. Graphing tools (using swing).
6. If  time permits, differential equation support (symbolic solver,Euler's approximation, Laplace transform).

Comment: +1 for giving a possible solution, but this lib seems a little old (latest update was in 2009)

Comment: it's not problem if the  library is old , specially if this  the library do Mathematics operation which never change , so may be you need to try it :)

Comment: sure! :) but maybe some performance or code improving should be done