# Performing symbolic math in Java

Tags: java, math

I'm writing a simple program in Java (I'm using Eclipse) that solves some simple equations by opening a file and reading the contents via a Scanner, and solves the equation, rewriting the file contents to be the result.

I want my program to be able to also perform symbolic integration and derivation. I have been searching for a way to do this but can't seem to find one - I've looked at Symja but couldn't figure out how to implement this into my code.

Basically, what I need are instructions on how to call integration/derivation methods inside my own Eclipse project. Example: I'd like to be able to say `someMethod.Integrate(function)` and have it perform the integration, or something of the sorts. Can someone provide me with a simple, easy to follow tutuorial on how to do this? Would DataMelt work?

Comment: Possible duplicate question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041487/compute-complex-math-integration-derivation

Comment: Symja looks like a good solution for what you are looking for: https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Apache Math?? http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/

Here you have an dervation/integration example: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html#a4.5_Integration

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is- can it do symbolic integration? That's what I want my program to do, not numeric. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use

[Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) or
[javacalculus](https://code.google.com/p/javacalculus/)

Comment: It seems apache commons math can't do symbolic integration, only numeric. Is this true?

Comment: Also, javacalculus looks like it has been inactive since 2009.

Comment: The question asked was how to do symbolic integration (delayed computation), not just some math library.